# Year-on-year change column in the data frame of monthly data

Tags: r

I am looking for the solution to my task. It is to add a new column to the data frame, which contains monthly data, that would have year-on-year change for each record that has a corresponding record of same month a year ago.

So, my code as of now is:

```
library(blsAPI)
cpi       <- blsAPI("CUUR0000SA0",2,TRUE)      
cpi$value <- as.numeric(cpi$value)
cpi$date  <- as.Date(                        
     paste0("1 ",cpi$periodName," ",cpi$year), 
     format = "%d %B %Y")
cpi <- cpi[order(cpi$date),]
```

I would like to add new column with YoY change value for `cpi$value` column.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2021-01-16", "2017-05-09"))
df |> dplyr::mutate(new = as.Date(Date) + 365)
#>         Date        new
#> 1 2021-01-16 2022-01-16
#> 2 2017-05-09 2018-05-09

library(lubridate)

df |>
  dplyr::mutate(new = as_date(Date) %m+% years(1))
#>         Date        new
#> 1 2021-01-16 2022-01-16
#> 2 2017-05-09 2018-05-09
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I am sorry for confusing request. Your proposal is decent, but what I needed was a bit different. This is how I solved my question: `cpi.ts    <- ts(cpi$value, start = c(cpi$year[1],month(cpi$date[1])), frequency = 12); cpi$yoy <- as.numeric((cpi.ts/lag(cpi.ts,-12)-1)*100)`